# Having trouble with an FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am currently trying to return the last 10 posts from my wall, however I am getting an empty return when I am testing it on the graph API explorer.

I am using:

`SELECT post_id, message FROM stream where source_id = me()`

Which is returning:

`{
  "data": [
  ]
}`

I believe I am granting the correct permissions for this query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my query which now works. I have changed the me() function and used my user ID directly.

Comment: Any idea as to why it wasn't working? I guess you should change your question and ask this. It's actually an interesting question.

Comment: I think it may have been to do with the server not identifying the function me() as the account the app belonged to.